# How to use a static ip address and a pod in podman-compose

Tags: podman

I have all ready created a network `test` with subnet `10.2.5.0/16` and also have create a pod `test` for this compose setup. I was not able to find a way to define the pod. Anyway when I try to check the networking with the following part in docker-compose.yml

```bash
    networks:
      test:
        ipv4_address: '10.2.5.2'
networks:
  test:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: test
      config:
        - subnet:  10.2.5.0/16
```

I get an error.

```bash
['podman', '--version', '']
using podman version: 4.3.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/podman-compose", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('podman-compose==1.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'podman-compose')())
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/podman_compose.py", line 1775, in main
    podman_compose.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/podman_compose.py", line 1022, in run
    self._parse_compose_file()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/podman_compose.py", line 1128, in _parse_compose_file
    raise RuntimeError(f"missing networks: {missing_nets_str}")
RuntimeError: missing networks: test
```

What is the right way to define them?